# ¿en java se puede convertir una cadena a genérico?

Tags: java, lista, archivo, polimorfismo, genericos

La cuestión es que estoy intentando leer una lista genérica desde un archivo para los hijos de un árbol n-ario en java con el método Split, pero al momento de ingresarlos, el Split genera un vector de String el cual al momento de castearlo a Comparable no se pasa el valor al value directamente si no al elemento, les dejo a continuación mi clases con sus paquetes:

```
package Negocio;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import Librerias.*;

public class Arbol <T>{
    
    private Nodo<T> raiz;
    public Arbol() {
        this.raiz = null;
    }
    public Nodo<T> getRaiz() {
        return raiz;
    }
    public void insertar(Comparable<T> elementoPadre, Comparable<T> elemento) throws PosicionIlegalException {
        if(existeElemento(elemento)) {
            Consola.Escribir("ERROR:El elemento "+elemento+" ya se encuentra en el arbol, por lo tanto no se agrego.");
        } else {
            raiz = insertar(raiz,elementoPadre,elemento,null);
        }
    }
    private Nodo<T> insertar(Nodo<T> arbol,Comparable<T> elementoPadre,Comparable<T> elemento, Nodo<T> nuevo) throws PosicionIlegalException{
        if( arbol == null ){
            arbol = new Nodo<T>(elemento);
        } else if(arbol.getElemento()==elementoPadre){
            Lista<Nodo<T>> hijos = new Lista<Nodo<T>>();
            nuevo = new Nodo<T>(elemento);
            hijos = arbol.getHijos();
            nuevo.setElemento(elemento);
            hijos.agregar(nuevo);
            //ordenarHijos(hijos, hijos.getTamanio());
            arbol.setHijos(hijos);
        } else {
            for(int i=0;i<arbol.getHijos().getTamanio();i++) {
                insertar(arbol.getHijos().getValor(i),elementoPadre,elemento,nuevo);
            }
        }
        return arbol;
    }
    public boolean existeElemento(Comparable<T> elemento) throws PosicionIlegalException {
        return existeElemento(raiz, elemento);
    }
    private boolean existeElemento(Nodo<T> raiz, Comparable<T> elemento) throws PosicionIlegalException {
        if (raiz!=null) {
            if (elemento == raiz.getElemento()) {
                return true;
            } else if(raiz.getHijos()!=null){
                for (int i = 0; i < raiz.getHijos().getTamanio(); i++) {
                    if (existeElemento(raiz.getHijos().getValor(i), elemento)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
        return false;
    }
    public void lecturaArchivo(String ubicacion) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File archivo = new File(ubicacion);
        Scanner s = new Scanner(archivo);
        try {
            // Leemos linea a linea el fichero
            while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                String linea = s.nextLine();
                if(raiz == null)
                    insertar(null,(Comparable<T>)linea);
                else {
                    String parts[] = linea.split("-");
                    insertar((Comparable<T>)parts[0],(Comparable<T>)parts[1]);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Mensaje: "+ex.getMessage()); 
        } finally {
            try {
                if (s != null) {
                    s.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex2) {
                System.out.println("Mensaje 2: "+ex2.getMessage()); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

----------------------------------------------clase nodo del árbol:

```
package Negocio;
import Librerias.Lista;

public class Nodo<T> {

    private Lista<Nodo<T>> hijos = new Lista<>();
    private Comparable<T> elemento; 
    public Nodo(Comparable<T> elemento) {
        this(elemento, new Lista<>());
    }
    public Nodo(Comparable<T> elemento, Lista<Nodo<T>> hijos){
        this.elemento = elemento;
        this.hijos  = hijos;
    }
    public Lista<Nodo<T>> getHijos() {
        return hijos;
    }
    public void setHijos(Lista<Nodo<T>> hijos) {
        this.hijos = hijos;
    }
    public Comparable<T> getElemento() {
        return elemento;
    }
    public void setElemento(Comparable<T> elemento) {
        this.elemento = elemento;
    }
}
```

---

```
package Librerias;

public class Lista<T> {

    /**
     * * Primer elemento de la lista
     */
    private NodoList<T> cabeza;
    /**
     * * Total de elementos de la lista
     */
    private int tamanio;

    /**
     * * Constructor por defecto
     */
    public Lista() {
        cabeza = null;
        tamanio = 0;
    }

    /**
     * * Devuelve el tamanio de la lista
     *
     *
     * @return tamanio
     */
    public int getTamanio() {
        return tamanio;
    }

    /**
     * * Consulta si la lista esta vacia
     *
     *
     * @return true cuando esta vacia , false cuando no
     */
    public boolean esVacia() {
        if (cabeza == null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * * Agrega un nuevo nodo al final de la lista
     *
     *
     * @param valor valor a agregar
     */
    public void agregar(T valor) {
        NodoList<T> nuevo = new NodoList<T>();
        nuevo.setValor(valor);
        if (esVacia()) {
            nuevo.setAnterior(null);
            cabeza = nuevo;
        } else {
            // agregar al final de la lista 
            NodoList<T> aux = cabeza;
            while (aux.getSiguiente() != null) {
                aux = aux.getSiguiente();
            }
            aux.setSiguiente(nuevo);
            nuevo.setAnterior(aux);
        }
        tamanio++;
    }

    /**
     * inserta un nuevo nodo en la lista
     *
     *
     * @param valor valor a agregar
     *
     * @param pos posicion donde se insertara el nodo
     *
     * @throws PosicionIlegalException excepcion en caso que la posicion no
     * exista
     */
    public void insertar(T valor, int pos) throws PosicionIlegalException {
        if (pos >= 0 && pos <= tamanio) {
            NodoList<T> nuevo = new NodoList<T>();
            nuevo.setValor(valor);
            // el nodo a insertar esta al comienzo de la lista 
            if (pos == 0) {
                nuevo.setSiguiente(cabeza);
                cabeza = nuevo;
                nuevo.setAnterior(null);

            } else {
                // El nodo a insertar va al final de la lista 
                if (pos == tamanio) {
                    NodoList<T> aux = cabeza;
                    while (aux.getSiguiente() != null) {
                        aux = aux.getSiguiente();
                    }
                    aux.setSiguiente(nuevo);
                    nuevo.setAnterior(aux);
                } else {
                    NodoList<T> aux = cabeza;
                    for (int i = 0; i <= pos - 2; i++) {
                        aux = aux.getSiguiente();
                    }
                    NodoList<T> siguiente = aux.getSiguiente();
                    aux.setSiguiente(nuevo);
                    nuevo.setSiguiente(siguiente);
                    nuevo.setAnterior(aux);
                }
            }
            tamanio++;
        } else {
            throw new PosicionIlegalException();
        }
    }

    /*
     * recorrer lista desde cabeza y luego desde final
     */
    public void RecorrerListaCabeza() throws PosicionIlegalException {
        for (int i = 0; i < tamanio; i++) {
            System.out.println("Lista en la posicion " + i + " tiene como contenido: " + getValor(i));
        }
    }

    public void RecorrerListaFinal() throws PosicionIlegalException {
        for (int i = tamanio; tamanio >= 0; i--) {
            System.out.println("Lista en la posicion " + i + " tiene como contenido: " + getValor(i));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Devuelve el valor de una determinada posicion
     *
     *
     * @param pos posicion
     *
     * @return el valor de tipo T
     *
     * @throws PosicionIlegalException
     */
    public T getValor(int pos) throws PosicionIlegalException {
        if (pos >= 0 && pos < tamanio) {
            T valor = null;
            if (pos == 0) {
                valor = cabeza.getValor();
                return valor;
            } else {
                NodoList<T> aux = cabeza;
                for (int i = 0; i <= pos - 1; i++) {
                    aux = aux.getSiguiente();
                }
                valor = aux.getValor();
            }
            return valor;
        } else {
            throw new PosicionIlegalException();
        }
    }
    public void setValor(int pos, T elemento) throws PosicionIlegalException {
        if (pos >= 0 && pos < tamanio) {
            if (pos == 0) {
                cabeza.setValor(elemento);
            } else {
                NodoList<T> nuevo = new NodoList<>();
                nuevo.setValor(elemento);
                NodoList<T> aux = cabeza;
                for (int i = 0; i <= pos - 1; i++) {
                    while (aux.getSiguiente() != null) {
                        aux = aux.getSiguiente();
                    }
                    NodoList<T> siguiente = aux.getSiguiente();
                    aux.setSiguiente(nuevo);
                    nuevo.setSiguiente(siguiente);
                    nuevo.setAnterior(aux);
                }
            }
        } else {
            throw new PosicionIlegalException();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Elimina un nodo en una determinada posicion
     *
     *
     * @param pos posicion
     *
     * @throws PosicionIlegalException
     */
    public void remover(int pos) throws PosicionIlegalException {
        if (pos >= 0 && pos < tamanio) {
            if (pos == 0) {
                // El nodo a eliminar esta en la primera posicion 
                cabeza = cabeza.getSiguiente();
                tamanio--;
            } else {
                NodoList<T> aux = cabeza;
                for (int i = 0; i <= pos - 2; i++) {
                    aux = aux.getSiguiente();
                }
                NodoList<T> prox = aux.getSiguiente();
                aux.setAnterior(aux);
                aux.setSiguiente(prox.getSiguiente());
                tamanio--;
            }
        } else {
            throw new PosicionIlegalException();
        }
    }
    /**
     * Clear elimina todos los nodos de la lista
     */
    public void limpiar() {
        cabeza = null;
        tamanio = 0;
    }
}
```

---

```
package Librerias;

public class NodoList<T> {

    private T valor;
    private int prioridad;
    NodoList<T> siguiente;
    NodoList<T> anterior;

    public NodoList() {
        valor = null;
        siguiente = null;
        anterior = null;
    }

    public T getValor() {
        return valor;
    }
    
    public int getPrioridad() {
        return prioridad;
    }

    public void setValor(T valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }
    
    public void setPrioridad(int prioridad){
        this.prioridad = prioridad;
    }

    public NodoList<T> getSiguiente() {
        return siguiente;
    }

    public void setSiguiente(NodoList<T> siguiente) {
        this.siguiente = siguiente;
    }
    
    public NodoList<T> getAnterior() {
        return anterior;
    }    
    
    public void setAnterior(NodoList<T> anterior) {
        this.anterior = anterior;
    }
}
```

---

```
package Librerias;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class PosicionIlegalException extends Exception {
    public PosicionIlegalException() { 
        super(" posicion ilegal en la lista "); 
    }
}
```

---

y bueno ya por el test simplemente paso la ubicación del .txt que tiene lo siguiente:

M

M-W

M-S

M-M

M-A

A-R

A-N

A-G

G-Y

G-O

---

aunque busco que funcione tanto con chars como con int, y en caso de que no sea ninguno, avise, en la primera linea del txt se supone que debo especificar el tipo de dato del cual será el arbol, (1 números, 0 caracteres), si alguien me puede ayudar con mi dilema, muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Aún a riesgo de equivocarme me atrevería a decir que el problema es que estás utilizando el == para comparar en lugar de la función compareTo del interface Comparable. Sino ¿Qué sentido tiene pasar el cast a Comparable a la función? Como por ejemplo, en ésta función de la clase Arbol:

```
private Nodo<T> insertar(Nodo<T> arbol,Comparable<T> elementoPadre,Comparable<T> elemento, Nodo<T> nuevo) throws PosicionIlegalException{
    if( arbol == null ){
        arbol = new Nodo<T>(elemento);
    } else if(arbol.getElemento()==elementoPadre){
        Lista<Nodo<T>> hijos = new Lista<Nodo<T>>();
        nuevo = new Nodo<T>(elemento);
        hijos = arbol.getHijos();
        nuevo.setElemento(elemento);
        hijos.agregar(nuevo);
        //ordenarHijos(hijos, hijos.getTamanio());
        arbol.setHijos(hijos);
    } else {
        for(int i=0;i<arbol.getHijos().getTamanio();i++) {
            insertar(arbol.getHijos().getValor(i),elementoPadre,elemento,nuevo);
        }
    }
    return arbol;
}
```

............

Comment: lo hice me mando un error de casteo, cuando pongo el (T) me manda error de casteo, muchas gracias por responder, la verdad es que el insertar me funciona muy bien, cuando lo llamo directamente con chars o enteros, pero cuando meto el String.split casteandolo, no se ingresan los valores o se ingresan mal.

Comment: ¿Cuando instancias la clase Arbol, T es de tipo String?

Comment: Sigo sin ver el objetivo de castear a Comparable para después ni usar su única función, el compareTo.  Además ese casteo daría error si instancias la clase arbos con un objeto que no implemente ese interface. Para limitar T solo a los tipos de objetos que implemente en interface Comparable lo mejor sería declararlo como tal: <T extends Comparable<?>>  así no te dejaraá hacer un new Arbol de un tipo de objeto que no implemente Comparable.

Comment: lo solucioné creando una clase Convertidor, con métodos que convierten de String a entero o character para poderlos ingresar, aunque de igual manera tienes razón con lo de usar comparable, sin usar su función compareTo, la verdad es que ni sabia que servia para eso, pero de todas formas seguí usando el ==, muchas gracias por responder y aclararme lo del compareTo, abajo dejare la clase Convertidor que utilicé y de que manera modifiqué la lectura de archivo.

Comment: Veo que te complicas demasiado. Si no vas a usar la funcionalidad de Comparable, no lo castees, no es necesario, pasa el objeto entero de tipo T.  Por otro lado, el == no sirve para comparar Strings porque java te hace una cache de las de los Strings en tiempo de compilación y todas las referencias al mismo String son el mismo objeto, sin embargo si en tiempo de ejecución creas otro String con la misma cadena, te crea un objeto distinto, por eso, aunque ambos Strings tuvieran "Hola Mundo" , serían diferentes objetos y el == daría false. los Strings hay que compararlos con .compareTo(String)

Answer (score 0):

A continuacion la solución que implemente y me sirvió, se que tiene errores, pero depronto ayude en algo a personas con mi misma duda.
SOLUCION:

```
Clase Converitidor:

    package Librerias;
    
    public class Convertidor {
        public static int StringToInt(String cadena) {
            return Integer.valueOf(cadena);
        }
        public static char StringtoChar(String cadena) {
            return cadena.charAt(0);
        }
    }
    
    Metodo de lectura en la clase arbol:
    
    public void lecturaArchivo(String ubicacion) throws FileNotFoundException {
            FileReader archivo = new FileReader(ubicacion);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(archivo);
            Scanner s = new Scanner(archivo);
            try {
                if(archivo.equals(null)) {
                    Consola.Escribir("El archivo no existe.");
                } else {
                    String cadena;
                    int tipoArbol=Convertidor.StringToInt(br.readLine());
                    if(tipoArbol==1) {
                        while((cadena = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            if(raiz == null)
                                insertar(null, (Comparable) Convertidor.StringToInt(cadena));
                            else {
                                String parts[] = cadena.split("-");
                                insertar((Comparable)Convertidor.StringToInt(parts[0]),(Comparable)Convertidor.StringToInt(parts[1]));
                            }
                        }
                    } else if(tipoArbol==0){
                        while((cadena = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            if(raiz == null)
                                insertar(null, (Comparable) Convertidor.StringtoChar(cadena));
                            else {
                                String parts[] = cadena.split("-");
                                insertar((Comparable)Convertidor.StringtoChar(parts[0]),(Comparable)Convertidor.StringtoChar(parts[1]));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println("Mensaje: "+ex.getMessage()); 
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (s != null) {
                        s.close();
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex2) {
                    System.out.println("Mensaje 2: "+ex2.getMessage()); 
                }
            }
        }
```

y perdon por no usar el compareTo con el comparable, aún no le entiendo muy bien :C